# How to save git diff as array in GitHub Action

Tags: git, shell, ubuntu, unix, github-actions

I'm trying to save the names of files from a `git diff` to an array in a GitHub action so that I can iterate through the array.

I can confirm I get the proper two commit hashes I need from the following (have also tried without `--short`) - had to convert branch names to commit hashes:

- `BASE_COMMIT=$(git rev-parse --short origin/$GITHUB_BASE_REF)`
- `HEAD_COMMIT=$(git rev-parse --short origin/$GITHUB_HEAD_REF)`

I would expect that the following would yield an array of file paths of modified files, but doesn't work:

```
    SAVEIFS=$IFS
    IFS=$'\n'
    mapfile my_array < <( git diff --name-only $BASE_COMMIT -- $HEAD_COMMIT )
    IFS=$SAVEIFS

    echo "${#myArray[@]}"
```

I also tried to use mapfile's [`-t` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) in place of messing with `$IFS`, but still yielded an empty array:

```
my_array=()
mapfile -t my_array < <( git diff --name-only $BASE_COMMIT -- $HEAD_COMMIT )
echo "${#myArray[@]}"
```

I've confirmed that `git diff --name-only $BASE_COMMIT..$HEAD_COMMIT`  gives me the results I expect when locally - running bash on Mac, `$BASE_COMMIT/$HEAD_COMMIT` replaced with appropriate commit hashes.

The operative part of the `.yml` is below, where `foo_bar.sh` is an executable script containing the snippets above.

```
name: Pull Request Action
on: pull_request
jobs:
  JobName1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Foo Bars
        run: |
          git fetch
          ./.github/foo_bar.sh
        shell: bash
```

I've looked around Stack Overflow and GH Action documentation but haven't found an answer that will work without using another Action from the marketplace (security said it's a no-go). I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: I don't think that `git diff` expression does what you want. The `--` marker separates a `<path>` argument from your `<commit>` arguments (see e.g. [the man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)), but you're applying a commit id after the `--`. At least when I try that locally, I get nothing output (because there are no file paths that match the argument).

Comment: I would ignore all the `mapfile` stuff in your action right now and make sure that, in the context of your action, that the `git diff` command is producing the output you expect. Until you get that right, the rest doesn't matter.

Comment: @larsks Thank you for the reply. I have a feeling it something with the `git diff` but when I run the similar command locally (GH Actions requires `..` to be replaced with `--`), the filenames for modified files are printed to stdout.

I'm also a bit new to this, do you have any advice given this?

Comment: So, again, I think it is your use of `--` that is causing your problem. Github actions does not require that you make that replacement. My advice remains: look at the output of your `git diff` statement in github actions and make sure *that* command produces the output you expect.

Comment: Besides all of the above, I'd wonder whether GitHub actions are executed with bash in the first place. If they use /bin/sh you may not be able to use arrays.

Comment: @torek It seems like you can [set the shell to bash](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#defaultsrun) in defaults for each job (which I'm using to match Actions in other repos in my org)

Comment: @larsks You were right. I looked back at my prior workflow logs to check the error, a couple words "jumped lines" in my head, I read the error wrong. the `--` was for revisions to paths, not revision to revision. My problem at that point was not properly getting the latest base branch merge commit.

Thank you for your help with this

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, attributed to @larsks

GitHub Actions doesn't require `..` to be replaced with `--` I misread an error earlier in troubleshooting to get the appropriate commits. The array works fine as long as `shell: bash` is set in the workflow .yml file.